# Calculate Power Level in Excel for 2 sample proportional test

Tags: r, statistical-power, excel

I have a need to calculate statistical power (the chance of making a Type II error) **within Excel** for a 2 sample proportional Z test.

Here's a example to better explain. Say I have two unequal samples n1 and n2. Within each sample, I have a number of individuals who have performed a specific conversion event. Lets call these converting individuals x1 and x2.

`n1=6500  n2=6000  x1=88  x2=50`

From these numbers I can calculated two conversion rates (p1 and p2), and using an alpha of 5% on a two tailed unpooled test, get my Z-score and p value. Again, all within Excel.

`p1 = x1/n1 = 0.0135`

`p2 = x2/n2 = 0.0083`

`std error = SQRT(p1*(1-p1)/n1 + p2*(1-p2)/n2) = 0.0019`

`observed difference of means = p2-p1 = 0.0052`

`Z-score= observed difference of means/std error = 2.8097`

`p-value = 2*NORM.S.DIST(-ABS(Z-score),TRUE) = 0.005`

As p is less that my alpha, I know my results are significant. Great! From there I can also calculate my Effect Size (the magnitude of difference between my two groups) using Cohen's H via the formula below.

`Cohen's H=2*(ASIN(SQRT(p1))-ASIN(SQRT(p2))) = 0.0504`

And because my Cohen's H value is less than .2, I know I am detecting a very small difference between these two groups.

Lastly, I need to demonstrate the chance of not making a Type II error (statistical power). **This is where I am stuck**. Using R (and the "pwr" package), this would be something like this with a result of 80.38%:

`if(!"pwr" %in% installed.packages()){install.packages("pwr")} library(pwr)`

`pwr.2p2n.test(h = 0.0504, n1 = 6500, n2 = 6000, sig.level = 0.05, alternative = 'two.sided')`

[image]

Here, n1 and n2 are my sample means, and h is my Effect Size (Cohen's H), but as mentioned, I cannot replicate this 80.38% number with an Excel formula.

Comment: `R` does not have a function called `pwr.2p2n.test`.  What's it supposed to do?

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/power-analysis-in-statistics-with-r/ It's calculating the power of a two proportion test with unequal samples

Comment: If you're asking about a function from some specific package (even in passing) it's important to include that information in your question.

Comment: Totally - my bad. Have updated the question to reflect the need for the external package.

Comment: Thank you -- but please don't make readers look up the manual page.  *Tell us what this function is intended to do* and *explain the meaning of its arguments.*  I, for one, find that I have to guess what exactly a "2 sample proportional Z test" is (because I can think of several situations that this could reasonably describe); and even then the meaning of `h` is unclear.

Comment: @whuber - added an example. Let me know if this helps or whether you recommend further edits to make my question clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some Background

What you want to do is a post hoc power analysis using the observed estimates, which means you use the your estimators as "true" parameters and calculate the probability of obtaining a significant result from this distribution.

This is a widely used but also somewhat questionable practice.  For the critic here's a blog post by Andrew Gelman, who's a fairly famous statistics professor:
https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/09/24/dont-calculate-post-hoc-power-using-observed-estimate-effect-size/

Here is the published Letter: https://journals.lww.com/annalsofsurgery/Citation/2019/01000/Don_t_Calculate_Post_hoc_Power_Using_Observed.46.aspx
There also exist some further follow ups on that.

### Your Problem

First of i won't use Excel formulas, but the only thing you need is $\Phi(x)$, which is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution, which you already used and its inverse $\Phi^{-1}(p)$.

That being out of the way: your p-value calculation and the `pwr::pwr.2p2n.test` function use slightly different convergences towards a standard normal test statistic.
For the p-value you used what is essentially a Wald-Test(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval_or_Wald_interval), while the R-function with Cohen's h builds on on $\arcsin$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Arcsine_transformation

#### Power Wald-Test

For the Power of your Wald-Test we assume that the observed $Z$-statisic of $\hat{z} = 2.8097$ is the true parameter so for any repetition of the experiment the new $Z$-statistic $\hat Z$ will be distributed according to $\mathcal{N}(\hat{z}, 1)$ and it will be counted as significant if $|\hat Z| > \Phi^{-1}(1 - \alpha/2) = 1.959964$, for $\alpha = 5\%$ in a tow sided test. Calculating that is straight forward, but don't forget the small probability, that you come out the other side and get a significant result of opposite sign: $$
P(|\hat Z| > 1.96) = 1 - \Phi(1.96 - \hat z) + \Phi(- 1.96 - \hat z) = 0.802265
$$
Pretty close to your result...

#### Power with Cohen's h

Basically the same but from the Wikipedia link we can learn, that $\mathrm{VAR}[\arcsin(\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}})] \approx \frac{1}{4n}$, from which we can conclude that the variance of Cohen's h is approximated by $\frac{1}{n_1 + n_2}$. Now the new $Z$-statistic is
$$
\hat z = \frac{0.0504}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1 + n_2}}} = 2.815191
$$

This is slightly bigger, so the Power will be slighter higher
$$
P(|\hat Z| > 1.96) = 1 - \Phi(1.96 - \hat z) + \Phi(- 1.96 - \hat z) = 0.8037881
$$
Perfection!

#### The calculations in R

I don't have Excel at home, but it should be straight forward to translate these over. `pnorm` is $\Phi$ and `qnorm` is $\Phi^{-1}$

```
qnorm(0.975)

pnorm(1.959964, mean = 2.8097)
1 - pnorm(1.959964, mean = 2.8097) + pnorm(-1.959964, mean = 2.8097)

n1=6500;  n2=6000;  x1=88;  x2=50;

p1 = x1/n1
p2 = x2/n2

h <- (asin(sqrt(p1))-asin(sqrt(p2)))
sd_h <- sqrt((1/(4*n1)) + (1/(4*n2)))
h/sd_h
0.0504/2/sd_h
1 - pnorm(1.959964, mean =0.0504/2/sd_h) + pnorm(-1.959964, mean =0.0504/2/sd_h)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: My takeaways were as follows. 1) read up more on the validity of this calculation re your comments in the 'Background' section. 2) calculate my Z score slightly differently: h / 2 / SQRT((1/(4*n1)) + (1/(4*n2))). Note: I also had to multiple your h value by 2 to get Cohens h in your answer above 3) Produce my desired result using the NORM.DIST function in Excel. =1-NORM.DIST(cv1,zscore,1,1)+NORM.DIST(cv2,zscore,1,1) where cv1 and cv2 are my critical values =NORM.S.INV(alpha/2) & =NORM.S.INV(1-alpha/2) where alpha = 5%

Comment: And to your point on the differing convergence methods for the Z stat is there a 'preferred' method? Should I stick with Wald's for my Z-stat and p value calculations, use a different method for my power calculation? If it makes a difference, I am usually dealing with large sample sizes and binary conversion data ie yes they converted or no they didnt.

Comment: 1) Don't overthink it. You can conclude that you have good power for h>= 0.05, but your data is also consostent with effects as low as 0.015 (-2 std.errors) 2) You can actually simplify with h/SQRT((1/n1) + (1/n2)). The 2 and the 4s cancel out. I just didn't clean up my code 3) looks good, but cv2 = -cv1, which might make it look nicer.

Comment: Regarding the your 3rd Comment: It doesn't matter unless you get probabilities very close to 0 or 1. Then you should prefer arcsine-transformations. Personally I'd define very close as one of p1, p2 being within 5 std.errors, 1 std.error being SQRT(p*(1-p)/n), of these edges. Otherwise just try to stay consistent.

Comment: Boom! Love it. Thanks a bunch.